# Downcasting PartialKeyPath to ReferenceWriteableKeyPath using generics?

Tags: swift, swift-keypath

I want a simple serialization implementation that stores values of various KeyPaths for a class and applies them.  I know this can be implemented by storing vars manually, but I'd prefer to use KeyPaths since it would be easier to add additional paths.  See example below:

```
class Model {
  var intValue: Int
  var boolValue: Bool
}

class ModelState {
  static let keyPaths = [ \Model.intValue, \Model.boolValue ]
  let values: [PartialKeyPath<Model>, Any]
  init(model: Model) {
    var values = [PartialKeyPath<Model>, Any]()
    Self.keyPaths.forEach { values[$0] = model[keyPath: $0 }
    self.values = values
  }
}

extension Model {
  var state: ModelState {
    get { return ModelState(model: self }
    set { newValue.values.forEach { (keyPath, value) in applyValue(keyPath, value) } }
  }

  private func applyValue<T>(_ keyPath: PartialKeyPath<Model>, value: T) {
    if let writeable = keyPath as? ReferenceWriteableKeyPath<Model, T> {
      self[keyPath: writeable] = value
    }
  } 
}
```

If I add a breakpoint in applyValue(), the keyPath is shown as the expected ReferenceWriteableKeyPath.  Similarly, if I attempt to typecast the KeyPath by explicitly stating the expected value type (e.g. `ReferenceWriteableKeyPath<Model, Int>` or `ReferenceWriteableKeyPath<Model, Bool>`), the typecast works correctly.  The code as written does not ever enter into the condition, however.  Does anyone see the issue with the code or know how to make this generic downcast work?

Comment: This is very much going _against_ the idea of key paths, whose entire selling point was to be type safe...

Comment: I don't see a contradiction between what I'm attempting here with the goal of type safety.  I want to safely downcast the KeyPath to the appropriate value type to apply it, but am only interested in doing so for a subset of the model's properties.  Do you have any advice on how this could work?

Comment: The compiler cannot guarantee the type safety of your code. It is not type safe in that sense. Anyway, the immediate problem is that `T` is always `Any`, so you are trying to cast to `ReferenceWritableKeyPath<Model, Any>`, which is not the same type as `ReferenceWritableKeyPath<Model, Int>`. However, the more fundamental problem is that you are using something that enforces type safety (writable key paths) in an unsafe way.

Comment: Okay, thank you, this is much more helpful.  I was debugging and printing the types of these variables using type(of:), but you're right that generics are a compile time feature so the typecast is always using T == Any.  Do you have a suggestion of a good way way to store and apply a subset of an object's properties?  Or is this ultimately going to require just creating a struct to hold the relevant properties and setting the struct to a new value?